# Theme ubercart "native" menu

Tags: drupal, themes, ubercart

This standart theme function seems not working for Ubercart menu

```
function theme_menu_tree($tree) {

  return '<ul class="my classes>'. $tree .'</ul>';
}
```

I've searched ubercart.org and did not find any answer on this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of menu you want to theme?

If the catalog block that you can use this theme function.

```
function theme_uc_catalog_block($menu_tree) {
  $output = '<ul class="catalog menu">';

  foreach ($menu_tree->children as $branch) {
    list($inpath, $html) = _uc_catalog_navigation($branch);
    $output .= $html;
  }

  $output .= '</ul>';

  return $output;
}
```